# AppendTrailingSlash with every url of website but need to skip this for admin area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

AppendTrailingSlash with every url of website but need to skip this for admin area.

Sample code that I have implemented

```
// Configure routing.
   services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
   {
        options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
        options.LowercaseUrls = true;
   });
```

I am using .net core 2.2 MVC application.

Comment: Hello, did you had the chance to try the solution. Do you need any further assistance on it?

Answer (score 1):

> AppendTrailingSlash with every url of website but need to skip this
> for admin area.

Well, using `ActionFilterAttribute` it can be achieved. Let assume I have below admin area:

[image]

In above scenario we can do as following:

**Action Filter:**

```
public class SkipTrailingSlashForAdminFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            var originalUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString();
         
            var isAdminArea = "/admin";

            if (originalUrl.Contains(isAdminArea))
            {
                var newUrl = originalUrl.TrimEnd('/');
                filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path = newUrl;
            }


            var checkUpatedTrailSlash = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString();

        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
            {
               
                options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
                options.LowercaseUrls = true;
            });
            services.AddMvc(dropTrailSlash => {
                dropTrailSlash.Filters.Add(new SkipTrailingSlashForAdminFilter());
            });
```

**Note:** Please bear in mind that `SkipTrailingSlashForAdminFilter` action filter should be placed after `Configure<RouteOptions>` order.

**Another Way:**

You can even set the annotation above the controller class where you would prefer to implement the rules. See the following code snippet:

```
[SkipTrailingSlashForAdminFilter]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]